# select lines with "some" word

Tags: regex, emacs

I've faces with the next one regular expression: `"^.*\\(?:some\\).*$"`.
I've understand `^` and `$` and `\\(` with `\\)` for back-referencing.

But what is the `?:some` construction?

Comment: `(?:foo)` is usually a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A group starting with `?:` is a non capturing group, means there will be no backreference, the `some` would be your search word.

`^` is an anchor to match the start of the line

`$` is an anchor to match the end of the line

Your expression would match e.g.

> Foobar some more text
>
> Foobar somemore text
>
> some

Comment: We're talking about Emacs regular expressions here, so grouping brackets *are* escaped. So it is a non-capturing group.

Comment: @phils I have never used regex in emacs, I updated my answer.